# Update 2 Error Adding MVC View

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015

Last night, I updated Visual Studio 2015 on my system from RTM to Update 2. I now get an error message when I try to add a new View to an ASP.Net MVC application I am working on:

> There was an error running the selected code generator:
>   'Expected 1 export(s) with contract name "NuGet.VisualStudio.IVs.PackageInstaller" but found 0 after applying applicable constraints.'

Any ideas on how to fix this? I had no trouble adding a few views to this project yesterday before I installed the update.

Answer (score 0):

### ***tl;dr - Reinstall NuGet Package Manager***

I know this is an old thread. But I encounter the same error message today and found no solution online that works for me. So I decided to answer on this old thread for future devs that will encounter the same error message.

The reason for my case is that my *NuGet Package Manager was missing*. 
I recently installed [Wekan](https://github.com/wekan/wekan/wiki/Install-Wekan-from-source-on-Windows) and it required me to install [Visual C++ 2015 Build Tools](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools), and I think that might be the culprit why NuGet was removed.

So, my solution is to download and reinstall NuGet Package Manager:

- In Visual Studio open *Extensions and Updates* Tools > Extensions and Updates (or by pressing ALT+T+U)
- On the left pane click *Online* and search for keyword *NuGet Package Manager for Visual Studio 2015*, download/install
- Restart VS

These are the other solution that worked for some (didn't work for me):

- [Try clearing the ComponentModelCache, the cache will rebuild next time VS is launched.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35815094/1638261)
- Delete NuGet.Config at C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Roaming\NuGet, and restart VS
- Unload/Reload project, Clean solution, Rebuild then restart VS

Answer (score -1):

Updating the VS2015 will force you to update after that the whole work you have done so far. Most of the references specially NuGet are changed or outdated in 2015. I am currently using vs2013 with MVC5. I would suggest you to update the references and find a solution about this NuGet package. It might be no longer available for this view you want to add. In addition, there is a similar topic with Q&A to your and it is accessible right here: [Unable to Install Any Package in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344232/unable-to-install-any-package-in-visual-studio-2015) . Take a look but VS2015 the free version is not that good for coding. Better download visual studio 2013 with update 5 and you will be much better. If you still want to keep it with VS2015, take a look at this and download it.

### VS2015 NuGet Manager:

https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d345edc-2e2d-4a9c-b73b-d53956dc458d