# Getting "project" nuget configuration is invalid error

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, nuget

I'm getting "[project] nuget configuration is invalid" error. I received an error like this before and used the 'Update Nuget package manager' solution mentioned here:

[Unable to Install Any Package in Visual Studio 2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344232/unable-to-install-any-package-in-visual-studio-2015)

I've also tried the other solutions mentioned in that link to no avail.

- **Restarting Visual Studio**
- **Deleting nuget.config**
- **Deleting packages.config**
- **Updating nuGet Package Manager.**

Also, I'm able to see the nuGet Packages at the solution level and other projects within this solution.

And, if I go to Package Manager Console (Tools -> NuGet Package Manager -> Package Manager Console), I can't see the projects having this issue in the project drop down, but I see the other projects in the solution.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

NOTE: This is mentioned in the question but **restarting Visual Studio** fixes the issue in most cases.

Updating Visual Studio to 'Update 2' got it working again.

`Tools -> Extensions and Updates ->Visual Studio Update 2`

As mentioned in the question and the link i posted therein, I'd already updated NuGet Package Manager to 3.4.4 prior to this and restarted to no avail, so I don't know if the combination of both these actions worked.

Comment: I had this error in Update 2, but Restarting VS fixed it for me

Comment: This update was hidden under `Python Tools Update` for me.

Comment: I just ran into this, and am already on Update 3. Restarting fixed it for me as well.

Comment: This worked for me, and also it makes sense because, I had changed versions of things in the web.config, then nuget wouldn't load

Answer (score 949):

Simply restarting Visual Studio worked for me.

Comment: This solution and many others have been listed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34910428/5159431). As mentioned in the question, this is a case where this and many of the listed solutions have already been tried

Comment: @AshwinNair Thank you for pointing that out.  I added this as an answer because I found this question when I was Googling the error message, and restarting VS was all I needed.  So the solutions you mentioned trying in your question actually solved my problem. :) I suspect others have found that to be the case for them as well.

Comment: It's good to know that one of the solutions mentioned in the question solved your problem. As I mentioned before, this question is a case where those 'solutions' that worked for others hadn't worked. As such, 'restarting VS' isn't an answer to THIS question. I hope people don't take it upon themselves to post the other three solutions as answers as well in case one of the 3 works for them.

Comment: Any project created using dotnet CLI and then opened on VS 2017 also faces the same problem, restarting VS fixed the problem for me too.

Comment: Closing the solution and reopening it worked for me, rather than restarting visual studio entirely.

Comment: I turned on my laptop and opened a new instance of VS. I cloned a project via 3rd party GIT extension. I noticed visual studio opened it as a folder and not a project, I'm not sure if this had any effect of initializing the NPM. It was completely useless though. Restarting Visual Studio and opening the .sln made everything work perfectly.

Comment: Find the package.config file , remove the references (if any ) causing the problem . After you install the packages ,it will get updated automatically

Comment: Still works in VS2019. Consistency FTW!

Comment: VS 2015 works too, thanks

Comment: Happened to me after moving some code to a shared project, then linking to it. Reliable fix in VS2019 16.3.0 Preview 1 :P